# Jenkins redirect plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am not super familiar with Jenkins. I just searched the web for "Jenkins Redirect Plugin" but no luck. I renamed a bunch of jobs and turns out it broke all the link names to the previous jobs. So now when one clicks a link in Github they get a 404.

My two options that I can see are:
1. Rename the jobs so they are named incorrectly again. Restoring the old links.
2. Install/write some redirect functionality

Really would like a #2 out there. Any such thing or does this need to be written or maybe there is a #3 out there?

Comment: Consider using haproxy. URL can be re-written with regular expression etc..